# Error in output after Loop is caused by strcat?

Tags: c, loops, strcat

I have the following code to append string to another in a loop.

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
        char src1[] = "name";
        int i;
        for (i=1;i<=5;i++){
                strcat(src1,"opps");
                printf("loop times %d\n",i);
        }
                printf("now src1 is:%s\n",src1);
        return 0;
}
```

To debug the code, I added `printf` statements to the code and compiled it. When I run, I get the following result:

**Output**

loop times 1
loop times 0
loop times 1886416641
now src1 is:nameoppsoppsopps

My question is "Why does `printf` loop 1886416641 times?" Also, the result also is not what I was expecting. Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: You are writing out of bounds. In this case, you're overwriting the loop-counter.

Comment: Rather than "result also is not what I was expecting.", more useful to post what was expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 5 bytes allocated to `str1` and the `strcat` will access out of bounds, then it may cause undefined behavior.

The number `1886416641` was just accidentally got.

You have to allocate enough memory to `str1` to get normal result.
example: `char src1[32] = "name";`

Comment: `1886416641` is *hardly* accidental: It's `0x70706F01`, so ascii `ppo'\1'`. Which means you can probably find out the OP's machine's endianness from it.

Comment: thanks ,i have extended the space of  memory to  S1 ,it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Your `src1[]` isn't large enough. When you append the second "opps" it overwrites `i`. The value 1886416641 is hex 70706f01: 0x70= 'p', 0x70= 'p', 0x6f= 'o'.

The compiler has rounded to the next 32-bit machine word. The stack in bytes looks like:

```
start:        loop1    loop2
src1[]:
    n
    a
    m
    e
    \0        o
    <fill>    p
    <fill>    p
    <fill>    s
i:
    00        \0    o
    00        00    p
    00        00    p
    01        02    s
                    \0
```

(stack not accurate; some elements are actually reversed - use it as an example)

Comment: To be clear "When you append the second "opps" it overwrites i" is an example of undefined behavior that resulted from `srtrcat()` writing beyond `src1[]`. It does explain OP's results - which may differ on another day/platform etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit detail to already existing answers, as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) of `strcat()`,

> `char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);`
>
> The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, **and the `dest` string must have enough space for the result. If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable; [...]

In case, your final string is having more length than that of the destination can store, you'll be accessing out of bound memory which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In your code, `src1` gets its size from the length of the initializer string. At a later point, if you want to store a lengthier one, you need to allocate more storage at the beginning, like

```
char src1[128] = "name";
```

or similar.